# Remote desktop from Windows and Mac to Ubuntu with multiple users, saved sessions and copy-paste

Tags: server, remote-desktop, vnc, xrdp

I've been trying to set up a remote desktop access to our computational server running Ubuntu Server 16.04 . The clients use both Windows and Mac. They absolutely require to be able to pick up their previous sessions and to copy-paste. So, basically I need these features to work:

1. Multiple users
2. Mac and Windows access
3. Session continuation
4. Copy-paste

So far I've broken my teeth with xRDP. While I have managed to deliver the first 3 points, I can't find a way to make copy-paste working. Even [this](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=9285) failed. Can you recommend me a different solution?

**Update**. I've managed to get everything running perfectly under 14.04 LTS on a virtual machine using [X11RDP-o-Matic](https://github.com/scarygliders/X11RDP-o-Matic), though it doesn't officially support 14.04. Anyway, it fails to work under 16.04 due to inclusion of `systemd`.

Comment: I know you are open to any solution, but it is important for others to know that your current solution  xRDP+`xcfe4`